Can FRI in STARK be used in Spartan?
Can FRI in STARK be applied to multilinear polynomials? I am reading the paper ''Spartan: Efficient and General-Purpose zkSNARKs without Trusted Setup'' which mentions that Spartan requires a polynomial commitment for multilinear polynomials. Can FRI in STARK satisfy Spartan’s requirements?
